# d3 - click event using React responding slow due to centroid coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am building out a map of the US using React and d3.
I've come across a peculiar scenario where, I assign a clickhandler on the jsx `path` element upon `render`.

For some reason I've noticed when I click, the event seems to fire immediately, (as I can console log) but the popover state takes a few milliseconds longer.
The weird nuances here is, if I remove the `x` and `y` attributes from the  `text` elements that should be rendered (see below, with `.state-label` as selector), and click... it responds as expected.
Not exactly sure why these `text` elements are prolonging the event from firing immediately and would appreciate any suggestion or ideas.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "components/general/NationalMap.css";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { geoPath, geoAlbersUsa } from "d3-geo";
import {
  STATE_LABELS
} from "components/shared/Variables";

export default class NationalMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  mapClicks = (event, d) => {
    console.log('clicked')
    this.setState({showPopover: true}) // 

  };

  projection = ($width, $height) => {
    return geoAlbersUsa()
      .scale($width * 1.1)
      .translate([$width / 2, $height / 2]);
  };

  path = () => {
    return d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection(1300, 1300 * 0.6));
  };

  getUSNamesX = d => {
    let path = this.path();
    let xCentroid = path.centroid(d)[0];

    if (d.properties.STUSPS === "FL") {
      xCentroid = xCentroid + 10;
    }
    return xCentroid || null;
  };

  getUSNamesY = d => {
    let path = this.path();
    let yCentroid = path.centroid(d)[1];

    if (d.properties.STUSPS === "FL") {
      yCentroid = yCentroid;
    }
    return yCentroid || null;
    //return !isNaN(path.centroid(d)[1]) ? yCentroid : null;
  };

  getStateLabel = abbrev => {
    let label;

    STATE_LABELS.forEach(l => {
      if (l.abbrev === abbrev) {
        label = l.label;
      }
    });
    return label;
  };

  getStateLabelClass = d => {
    let stateclass_name = this.getStateClass(d);

    if (typeof stateclass_name !== "undefined") {
      if (stateclass_name.includes("full")) {
        stateclass_name = "state-label-active";
      }
      return stateclass_name;
    }
  };

  getStateClass = d => {
    if (typeof this.props.stateData !== "undefined") {
      let sc = [];
      let stateAbbrev = d.properties.STUSPS;
      let state = this.props.stateData[d.properties.STUSPS];

      if (typeof state !== "undefined") {
        if (state.race === "Y") {
          if (typeof state.win != "undefined") {
            if (state.win != " ") {
              sc.push(stateAbbrev + " " + state.win + "full");
            } else {
              sc.push(stateAbbrev + " Noresult");
            }
          } else {
            sc.push(stateAbbrev);
          }
        } else if (state.race === "N") {
          sc.push(stateAbbrev + " Noelection");
        }
      }
      return sc.join().replace(",", " ");
    }
  };

  render() {
    const usMapData = this.props.usData;
    const usDistricts = this.props.usDistrictsData;
    const currentMap = this.props.currentMap;
    const $width = 1300;
    const $height = $width * 0.6;
    const LOADING = this.state.isReady;


    return (
      <div className="nat-map-wrap">
        <div className="map-wrapper">
        {showPopover &&
          <div>My Popover</div>
        }
          {!LOADING && (
            <div className="presgov-map ismap">
              <svg
                viewBox={"0 10 " + $width + " " + $height}
                className={"natMapWrap " + currentMap}
              >
                {usMapData && (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <g className="state-g-tag">
                      <g id="states" className="zoom-g">
                        {usMapData.map((d, i) => (
                          <path
                            key={`path-${i}`}
                            d={geoPath().projection(
                              this.projection($width, $height)
                            )(d)}
                            className={"state " + this.getStateClass(d)}
                            stroke="#fff"
                            strokeWidth={0.5}
                            onClick={evt =>
                              this.mapClicks()
                            }
                          />
                        ))}
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="statenames">
                      <g className="zoom-g">
                        {usMapData.map((d, i) => (
                          <text
                            key={`text-${i}`}
                            x={this.getUSNamesX(d)}
                            y={this.getUSNamesY(d)}
                            textAnchor="middle"
                            className={
                              "state-label "
                            }
                          >
                            {d.properties.STUSPS}
                          </text>
                        ))}
                      </g>
                    </g>
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}
              </svg>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Define your state in the constructor. `this.state = { showPopover: false }`. State keys should not mutate.

Comment: Right. Noted. The click issue still persists though.

Comment: Where is your `this.path()` method? I don't see it anywhere and it's called in `getUSNames`

Comment: @izb  Yup, forgot to copy/paste that in. Just added it above.

Comment: have you tried combining getUSNamesX and getUSNamesY into a single function or caching the results so that the `path.centroid(d)` is only performed once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click you are performing 4 expensive operations:

1. `this.path()`, which is initing both the projection and path!
2. `path.centroid(d)[0]`
3. `this.path()`
4. `path.centroid(d)[1]`

First, I'd create `projection` and `path` as a member variables, so you stop recreating them (twice) on each click.  Second, only call path.centroid once something like this (all code untested):

```
getUSNamesXY = d => {

    let centroid = this.path.centroid(d); //path is member

    if (d.properties.STUSPS === "FL") {
      centroid[0] = centroid[0] + 10;
    }
    return centroid || null;
  };
```

And:

```
<g className="zoom-g">
{usMapData.map((d, i) => (
  <text
    key={`text-${i}`}
    transform="translate(" + {this.getUSNamesXY(d)} + ")"
    textAnchor="middle"
    className={
      "state-label "
    }
  >
    {d.properties.STUSPS}
  </text>
))}
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up implementing your suggestion, and seems to have helped. Since there are other maps in play, I ended up creating the text elements once and referecning it using `use` tag.